# Parsing nested JSON into pandas DataFrames

Tags: python, json, pandas

I'm reading data from a target legacy system that has stock earnings data in it. The data is exported in JSON format into modules such as this earnings module.

```
earnings_dict = {
 "earningsChart": {
      "quarterly": [
           {
                "date": "1Q2018",
                "actual": {
                     "raw": 0.12,
                     "fmt": "0.12"
                },
                "estimate": {
                     "raw": 0.05,
                     "fmt": "0.05"
                }
           },
           {
                "date": "2Q2018",
                "actual": {
                     "raw": 0.21,
                     "fmt": "0.21"
                },
                "estimate": {
                     "raw": 0.19,
                     "fmt": "0.19"
                }
           },
           {
                "date": "3Q2018",
                "actual": {
                     "raw": 0.16,
                     "fmt": "0.16"
                },
                "estimate": {
                     "raw": 0.21,
                     "fmt": "0.21"
                }
           },
           {
                "date": "4Q2018",
                "actual": {
                     "raw": 0.07,
                     "fmt": "0.07"
                },
                "estimate": {
                     "raw": 0.14,
                     "fmt": "0.14"
                }
           }
      ],
      "currentQuarterEstimate": {
           "raw": 0.15,
           "fmt": "0.15"
      },
      "currentQuarterEstimateDate": "1Q",
      "currentQuarterEstimateYear": 2019,
      "earningsDate": [
           {
                "raw": 1556496000,
                "fmt": "2019-04-29"
           },
           {
                "raw": 1556841600,
                "fmt": "2019-05-03"
           }
      ]
 },
 "financialsChart": {
      "yearly": [
           {
                "date": 2015,
                "revenue": {
                     "raw": 74977000,
                     "fmt": "74.98M",
                     "longFmt": "74,977,000"
                },
                "earnings": {
                     "raw": -15668000,
                     "fmt": "-15.67M",
                     "longFmt": "-15,668,000"
                }
           },
           {
                "date": 2016,
                "revenue": {
                     "raw": 105586000,
                     "fmt": "105.59M",
                     "longFmt": "105,586,000"
                },
                "earnings": {
                     "raw": -8281000,
                     "fmt": "-8.28M",
                     "longFmt": "-8,281,000"
                }
           },
           {
                "date": 2017,
                "revenue": {
                     "raw": 143803000,
                     "fmt": "143.8M",
                     "longFmt": "143,803,000"
                },
                "earnings": {
                     "raw": 9716000,
                     "fmt": "9.72M",
                     "longFmt": "9,716,000"
                }
           },
           {
                "date": 2018,
                "revenue": {
                     "raw": 190071000,
                     "fmt": "190.07M",
                     "longFmt": "190,071,000"
                },
                "earnings": {
                     "raw": 19967000,
                     "fmt": "19.97M",
                     "longFmt": "19,967,000"
                }
           }
      ],
      "quarterly": [
           {
                "date": "1Q2018",
                "revenue": {
                     "raw": 42340000,
                     "fmt": "42.34M",
                     "longFmt": "42,340,000"
                },
                "earnings": {
                     "raw": 4320000,
                     "fmt": "4.32M",
                     "longFmt": "4,320,000"
                }
           },
           {
                "date": "2Q2018",
                "revenue": {
                     "raw": 47240000,
                     "fmt": "47.24M",
                     "longFmt": "47,240,000"
                },
                "earnings": {
                     "raw": 7474000,
                     "fmt": "7.47M",
                     "longFmt": "7,474,000"
                }
           },
           {
                "date": "3Q2018",
                "revenue": {
                     "raw": 50126000,
                     "fmt": "50.13M",
                     "longFmt": "50,126,000"
                },
                "earnings": {
                     "raw": 5524000,
                     "fmt": "5.52M",
                     "longFmt": "5,524,000"
                }
           },
           {
                "date": "4Q2018",
                "revenue": {
                     "raw": 50365000,
                     "fmt": "50.37M",
                     "longFmt": "50,365,000"
                },
                "earnings": {
                     "raw": 2649000,
                     "fmt": "2.65M",
                     "longFmt": "2,649,000"
                }
           }
      ]
 },
 "financialCurrency": "USD"}
```

As you see, the JSON is nested with some meta data in the top level of the dictionary that is easy to read using something like pandas.io.json_normalize.

```
df = pd.io.json.json_normalize(earnings_dict)

df
Out[13]: 
  earningsChart.currentQuarterEstimate.fmt  ...                             financialsChart.yearly
0                                     0.15  ...  [{'date': 2015, 'revenue': {'raw': 74977000, '...

[1 rows x 9 columns]
```

But, it misses the nested lists of dictionaries that include multiple years and quarters of earnings data.   eg. the quarterly and yearly lists just get added to the Dataframe as a list of dictionaries.

I would presume this was originally several SQL tables with foreign keys.

I've read through the [json_normalize](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.io.json.json_normalize.html) docs and I can't seem to work out how to parse through the dictionary using the record_path and meta arguments.

I suppose I could use json_normalize or even create DataFrames from dictionaries at multiple levels of the nest.  It looks like I would need at least 5 -- one for the meta data and 4 for the 2 annual and yearly tables.

### Bonus:

How would you approach storing this?  Would you store it in a NoSQL string database or persist it in SQL?   My requirements are to do fairly low load, lightweight analysis which will require some views and graphics using pandas and matplotlib.

thanks for your help!

Comment: can you please show an expected output, thanks